# Forecasting time series regression in R using lm and lag

Tags: r, lm

I would like to predict using a linear model in R.  The model that I have is of the form `lm(y~ lag(x))`.  It seems like I should be able to predict using the predict function, but this does not look ahead into the future.

Here is the lag function that I have been using from within R.

```
lag1 = function (x) c(NA, x[1:(length(x)-1)])
```

This lag function adds an NA at the beginning of the data, shifts everything down, and cuts off the last observation.

I am mostly interested in the predictions made on the last line of the data.  This line of data seems to be ignored by the fitted and predict functions.

The best workaround I have found was to multiply each of the model coefficients by each of my dependent variables, and add them up for each prediction.  None of the dependent variables are lagged at this point, when I set up this equation.  The problem with this is that each time I change the model formula, the names of the variables have to be changed to match the new formula.  It seems like there should be a more intuitive solution to this.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Did you give new `x` values to the `predict()` function as the second argument?

Comment: Simply feed the future regressor values to the `newdata` parameter of `predict.lm()`. Make sure they are in a `data.frame` with the same names as used in the formula in `lm()`.

Comment: @Stephan Kollasa, For time series data your solution unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 19):

Estimating with lags and using model for predicting is a sore point in base R. Here is the example:

```
set.seed(1)
y<-ts(rnorm(10))
x<-ts(rnorm(10))
lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.2006      -0.2749  

>    lm(y~lag(x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ lag(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       lag(x)  
     0.2006      -0.2749
```

Notice that in both cases the result is the same. This happens because of the somewhat peculiar behaviour of the default lag function. Compare `x` and `lag(x)`

```
 x
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  1.51178117  0.38984324 -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621  0.82122120
[10]  0.59390132
> lag(x)
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 9 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  1.51178117  0.38984324 -0.62124058 -2.21469989  1.12493092 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.94383621  0.82122120
[10]  0.59390132
```

As you can see the data is the same, only the attributes, in this case the time, are different. Hence the lm sees the same data, since it ignores the attributes. There are several ways of working around this behaviour. Here are few.

First you can convert the data to time series format for which the lag behaviour is "standard".  One of such formats is `xts` from package `xts`:

```
yy<-xts(y,as.Date(1:10))
xx<-xts(x,as.Date(1:10))
lm(yy~xx)

Call:
lm(formula = yy ~ lag(xx))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      lag(xx)  
     0.2754      -0.2798
```

See now the coefficient is different, since `lag` now correctly shifts the data:

```
lag(xx)
                  [,1]
1970-01-02          NA
1970-01-03  1.51178117
1970-01-04  0.38984324
1970-01-05 -0.62124058
1970-01-06 -2.21469989
1970-01-07  1.12493092
1970-01-08 -0.04493361
1970-01-09 -0.01619026
1970-01-10  0.94383621
1970-01-11  0.82122120
```

Another way is to estimate the regression using the function `dynlm` from package **dynlm**:

```
dynlm(y~L(x))

Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 2, End = 10

Call:
dynlm(formula = y ~ L(x))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         L(x)  
     0.2754      -0.2798
```

This covers the estimation. Now predicting is trickier. To get the fitted values you can simply use `predict` function:

```
predict(dynlm(y ~ L(x)))
          2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.14757748  0.16632219  0.44920672  0.89503027 -0.03934318  0.28796556  0.27992365  0.01132412  0.04562977 
predict(lm(yy ~ lag(xx)))
          2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10 
-0.14757748  0.16632219  0.44920672  0.89503027 -0.03934318  0.28796556  0.27992365  0.01132412  0.04562977
```

Predicting ahead in a future though presents a problem. The default behaviour of `predict` function is to expect `newdata` argument. But for one step ahead forecast in this case, no new data is required. So standard `predict` function will not work in this case. I would love to see a general solution for this problem, but in my knowledge different packages provide different ways of getting such forecasts and if you do not want to write the function yourself you need to cast your model in a form which is required by a specific forecasting function from a specific package. And you need to know that package pretty well.

One of such packages is **midasr** (of which I am developer). One step ahead forecast for such model would be implemented in the following way:

```
midas_u(y~mls(x,1,1))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ mls(x, 1, 1), data = ee)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  mls(x, 1, 1)  
      0.2754       -0.2798  

forecast(midas_u(y~mls(x,1,1)),newdata=list(x=NA))
[1] 0.1092301
```

The package **midasr** works with mixed frequency data. The function `mls` has 3 arguments, data, lag numbers and frequency ratio. In this case the frequency is the same so the third argument is 1. In that case the function works exactly as the function `lag` for `xts` objects. For forecasting it is necessary to supply new data. As we do not know it we supply the NA which works in this case, since one-step ahead forecasts in this case needs only the data which we already know.

The last value of `x` is  0.59390132, so you can check that the result is the correct one directly

```
> 0.59390132*(-0.2798)  +0.2754
[1] 0.1092264
```

The answer is correct to 4 decimal places, since I used the coefficients with 4 digit accuracy.